Creating a kql time series chart out of one big snapshot
I would like to create a time chart that shows me how many tickets of the type type1 or type2 did not have the status closed in the past and were not in the iteration path path1 or path2 e.g. on a weekly base.
What does this issue make so difficult?

The data of this database is gathered in snapshots (1 snaptshot per
day) whereas only 7 snapshots exist at a time.

This means, if a new snapshot is being created, the oldest snapshot is being deleted at the same time. I suppose this has been chosen due to storage space reasons.
Every snapshot (column "Asof") thus consists of ALL data, with the latest snapshot having more data than the snapshot before, etc.
Besides of Asof column, the snapshot also consists of various other useful data (colums), which are:

SystemId as ticket number with the data type number

SystemAreapath as path of the ticket in the system with the data type “String”

SystemIterationpath with the data type string

SystemWorkitemtype as ticket type with the data type string

SystemState as status of the ticket with the data type string

SystemCreateddate as time when the ticket was created, data type time

MicrosoftVstsCommonActivateddate as the time when the ticket was started to be processed, data type time

MicrosoftVstsCommonCloseddate as the time when the ticket was closed, data type time

Asof as the time of the snapshot of the data, data type time

MicrosoftVstsCommonStatechangedate as the time of the last status change of the ticket, data type time


So, how does the query need to look to achieve the above mentioned result? I have no influence on how the database is created. I need to take the database as it is.
I tried some things but nothing comes close at all to what is really
needed. I don't know how to extract the data from the snapshot.

Could you share what you tried with? It will be easy to understand the issue you are facing with.
